how to redirect Github pages
I use github pages for the libraries I created on github. The README.md file is published directly on my main site in html. I keep English documentation in README.md and there is no problem. For the ones in different languages, I keep files like tr.md, fr.md. These files are accessed on the site as example.com/tr, example.com/tr.html, example.com/fr and example.com/fr.html. Github automatically synchronizes canonical, og:url values to .html. That's why google webmaster tools gives me an error, since the site is entered both as .html and without html, it loses ranking. How can I automatically redirect to .html when entering the non-.html one? I did some research for config.yml but I couldn't understand it. My main site is fine but I want the .md files I made for different languages to open automatically and only as .html.
